# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium. My application shows an error page. It throws the following error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.102)
Stacktrace:
```

This is my code

```
    from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:path/in/the/pc/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')    ## to initialize the webdriver to the Selenium 
driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/base')
```

How can I resolve the above error?

Answer (score 5):

```
driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/base')
```

make sure 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/base' you can reach this with chrome, nothing wrong with your code just try another link.

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

hope it can solve your problem

Comment: thanks Charles for your answer, it work with the google url but note my app url

Comment: the problem is that the two file are in the same project so i can't run the app file and the test file together. however it's true that that link don't work wen the test is running so what i do ?

Comment: maybe you can try async but if you want to keep it simple just split your project

Comment: how to do that you mean have two folder ?

Comment: Because in the tutorial it work just fine ven they are in the same folder and the app file won't running